# Setting input table name in Kusto query depending on variable?

Tags: azure-data-explorer

**Summary**

Depending on an input parameter I would like to use table1 or table2 for Kusto query.

**Background**

I've got a Kusto table, e.g. "table_all",  with webserver access logs, lots of rows for all customer traffic. Currently I am adding a second table that contains the number of hits per customer per minute or per hour. ("table_aggregated")

To visualise this I am using Grafana with Kusto to plot number of hits per customer over time. The Grafana dashboard contains a query like

```
table_all
| where $__timeFilter(event_timestamp)
| where customer == "$customer"
| summarize count(), bin(event_timestamp, $__interval)
```

which works ok to plot the number of hits of a particular customer over time.

Depending on Grafana's time range view I would like to use either table_full or table_aggregated as input into the query.

When a full month or more is selected in Grafana $__interval is set to 1h, and I could leverage the table with aggregated data.

Is there a way to build the input table name from the value of $__interval?

Comment: Same Question I am facing. Any luck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could potentially use `union` to achieve that: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/unionoperator

for example:

```
let T1 = range x from 1 to 3 step 1;
let T2 = range x from 11 to 13 step 1;
let _interval = 7h;
union
(T1 | where _interval < 5h),
(T2 | where _interval >= 5h)
```

Will return the numbers `11,12,13`.

And if you replace `7h` with, say, `3h`, it'll return the numbers `1,2,3`